# is there an easier way to split/rebuild a string?

Tags: java, string, split

currently I am using `String.split("")` like so:

```
String[] tmp = props.get(i).getFullName().split("\\.");
String name = "";
for(int j = 1; j < tmp.length; j++){
    if(j > 1){
        name = name + "." + tmp[j];
    }
    else
        name = name + tmp[j];
}
```

my String is in the format of `first.second.third...n-1.n` and all i really need to do is get rid of `first.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use

```
String s = "first.second.third...n-1.n";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf('.')+1);
// or
s = s.replaceFirst(".*?\\.", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
second.third...n-1.n
```

Comment: @Baz Time to take a break. ;)

Comment: looks good. It's been a little while since i did reg exp can you explain `(".*?\\.", "")`?

Comment: @DVK A `replaceFirst(".*\\.", "")` will indeed result in a greedy behavior, and prints `n`...But the `?` character makes it into a different quantifier, that has a reluctant behavior. Basically, `*?` **is itself a single quantifier** (`reluctant *`), and **not two** separate ones (not `* + "once or not at all"`).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `java.util.regex` and execute a regex instead.

The regex to match `first.` is `^[^.]+[.]`

```
String s = "first.second.third...n-1.n";
s.replaceAll('^[^.]+[.]', '');
```

Comment: I took a reg ex class and i swear it all went out the window afterwards. I think i need to read up a little more.
thanks for the quick response

Comment: @Phox - I develop in Perl (largely) for a living. Regexes are easy when you do them regularly (pun intended)

Comment: yea I've done very little perl code (i think it might have been the reg ex class or a follow upclass) they are crazy powerful

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe that, in this case in which the whole text before a well-defined separator is to be removed, a `substring` approach is faster than using a regex. In that case, Peter's first solution should only lose (speedwise) to a custom-coded function.