# What is more efficient: replaceFirst(), or replaceAll() with an anchored regex?

Tags: java, regex, performance

We have a string `String s = "first.second.third...n-1.n";`

Which of the two regex approaches are more efficient in Java?

```
s = s.replaceFirst(".*?\\.", "");
```

or

```
s = s.replaceAll('^[^.]+[.]', '');
```

They do the same thing, but I wonder which one is faster?

The differences are:

1. using anchored regex vs. `replaceFirst()` to only match the first instance
2. using non-greedy `*?` vs a non-dot character class `[^.]`
3. using `\\.` literal vs. `[.]` character class.

I would prefer an answer which would benchmark or explain the performance effect of those separately.

Comment: I don't have access to javac, so can't benchmark. The question originated from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218965/is-there-an-easier-way-to-split-rebuild-a-string

Comment: You probably meant `replaceAll` with the anchored version, right? The plain `replace` is not taking a regex.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I went ahead and fixed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second regexp is more efficient, because it does not backtrack.

Here is a [link](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance) to a nice article explaining the details. The article explains how the expression

```
<.*?>
```

takes 25 steps, while the expression

```
<[^>]*>
```

takes only five to find a match in a `<0123456789>` string, illustrating each of the steps the regex engine needs to take in order to produce a match.

There should be no difference between `\\.` and `[.]` - good regexp engines will convert both sub-expressions to the same compiled expression.

The anchored version with `replaceAll` is not doing the same thing as non-anchored `replaceFirst`, because the anchored version will not find a match when a dot `.` is the first character in the string. You can fix this by replacing `+` with a `*`.

With this difference out of the way, `replaceAll` will spend a little more time checking that there are no other matches (and there wouldn't be, because your expression is anchored), but that would not be significant for strings with long initial runs containing no dots.

Comment: This addresses difference #2 nicely. Any difference from #1 and #3?

Comment: Note that `replaceAll` is not at all the point. Why not use `replaceFirst` with the more efficient regexp, since only one replacement is made, anyway? `s.replaceFirst("^[^.]+\\.", "")` will work perfectly and will be the fastest (or exactly the same, since the anchor can be used to optimize `replaceAll`).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The result will be exactly the same, yet `replaceFirst` would be slightly faster, because there will be no second call to `Matcher`'s `find` method.